# populate multiple dropdown using mysql ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two multiple drop down countries and operators. The operator multiselect dropdown will populate on the basis of multiple countries dropdown. It only works if i chose one country from the dropdown,it will not show options of other selected country if i select more than one country.

html code:

```
<select name="ind" class="form-control" id="select" multiple placeholder="Select Countries" >
                <option value="0">Select Countries</option>
                <?php $sqlfu=$con->prepare("select `id`,`country_name` from `countries` order by `country_name` ") or  die(mysqli_error($con));
                $sqlfu->execute()or  die(mysqli_error($con));
                $resfu=$sqlfu->get_result();
                while($rowfu=$resfu->fetch_array())
                { $jind=$rowfu['id'];?>
                <option value="<?php echo $jind;?>"><?php echo ucwords($rowfu['country_name']);?></option>
                 <?php } ?> 

                  </select>

<select name="operators" class="form-control" id=operators" multiple placeholder="Select Mobile Operators" style="width:50%;"></select>
```

Following is my ajax code:

```
<script>
$("#select").change(function(){
    var a=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:'operator.php',
        data:{'id':a,'isAjax':true},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data)
        {
            var select=$("#sel"),options='';
            select.empty();

            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                options +="<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>"+data[i].operator+"</option>";
            }
            select.append(options);
        }
    });
});
```

operator.php:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$a=implode("', '", $id);
$result=array();
$sql=$con->prepare("select `id`,`operator` from `operators` where `c_id`=?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$a);
$sql->execute() or die(mysqli_error($con));

$res=$sql->get_result();
while($row=$res->fetch_array())
{
$result[]=array('id'=>$row['id'],'operator'=>$row['operator']);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: `select.empty();` looks like culprit here

Comment: @AniketSahrawat solved but now if i deselect country the operator of that country is not removing from the operator dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below line in operator.php:

```
$sql=$con->prepare("select id,operator from operators where c_id=?");
```

it is always returning single record so I had done it in loop like below

```
$result = array();
foreach ($id as $a) {
    $sql = $conn->prepare("select id,operator from operators where c_id=?");
    $sql->bind_param("s", $a);

    $sql->execute() or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $res = $sql->get_result();

    while ($row = $res->fetch_array()) {
        $result[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'operator' => $row['operator']);
    }
}

$res->close();
$conn->close();
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: its working but when i deselect a country it does not remove the operators from the dropdown

Comment: thanks its working perfectly now just have to add select.empty() in jquery

Answer (score 0):

collect multiple id in a variable and pass to operator.php like

```
     var a = [];
$('#select').each(function() {
    a.push($(this).val())
});
```

you already implode id after imploding explode id

```
$pin1 = explode(",",$a);
            $pin2 = sizeof($pin1);
            for($i=0; $i<=$pin2; $i++)
               {
  $id = $pin1[$i];
write your query here for matching c_id with $id 
}
```

after that you can explode id and match with your c_id in loop.

Comment: I get every value selected of #select using this method

Comment: remove option and make array for variable a

Comment: can you please explain a little bit please

Comment: i have edited logic , actually i am working on codeigniter ,still i put my logic

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Ajax calling. You are calling the server side script on **onChange** event. You should Collect the multiple value while user is selecting multiple countries like below

```
var selectedValues = $("#select").val();
```

Now make HTTP request to your Ajax URL. And use the code below.....

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$a=implode("', '", $id); //you must escape the string
$result=array();
$sql=$con->prepare("select `id`,`operator` from `operators` where `c_id` in('$a')");
$sql->bind_param("s",$a);
$sql->execute() or die(mysqli_error($con));

$res=$sql->get_result();
while($row=$res->fetch_array())
{
     $result[]=array('id'=>$row['id'],'operator'=>$row['operator']);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

You should use MySQL IN function